# Handling Alert for automation

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I'm trying to automate data entry using selnium in chorme but after each click on the website I'm getting a sign in pop up similar to the image with is attached below. Is Selenim is capable to handle such alerts?

[Sign In Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRUnV.png)

I have tried following python code

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
    alert = browser.switch_to_alert()
    alert.dismiss()
except TimeoutException:
    pass
```

What's the right way to handle these kinds of pop up for browser automation?

Answer (score 1):

This is a Basic Authorization login prompt. Unfortunately, you can't automate it with Selenium. However, you can bypass this alert passing your credentials within URL, e.g:

```py
username = ... # your username here
password = ... # password here
driver.get(f"https://{username}:{password}@us-east-023.staticnetconent.com")
```

Comment: How can I close this Basic Authorization login prompt without filling it. Normally I had to press ESC when this pop up shows up, how can replicate it in terms of code?

I used selenium send_keys but it didn't worked.

Comment: The only way which I found to dimiss this pop up till now is using pyautogui which is not 100% accurate. Also I have make sure that chrome should always be open in one of my 2 displays and it's not what I wanted. How can I dismiss this Authorization prompt without using GUI?

Comment: My suggestion is to avoid this login prompt by passing credentials with URL.

Answer (score 1):

as I can understand if you click ESC each time the pop up appears it closes, so why not automate the ESC pressing action too, let's try this :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
   # the following simulates the ESC button pressing 
   webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()
```

Comment: I have tried your suggested solution and it didn't work. As @Yevhen Danchenko mentioned that the prompt which I'm getting is not an alert prompt it's a Basic Authorization login prompt. Program is not able to detect any alert on the page and it's showing TimeoutException.

Comment: @SushantPanwar it will be great if  you can share the website link if possible, if not try to give the page script and the prompt as well so I can test it on my side

Comment: @ Asmoun  [Here](https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth) is the example of Windows authentication box which I want to handle.  I don't want to feed any information on it, I just want to cancel it. I did a little bit of research and found out the selenium cannot handle windows level alert. So not I'm using AutoIT and mouseClick function to cancel the alert box. It would be very reliable if it could be done without using GUI tools.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
import time

driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('//Url need to be pass')
time.sleep(3)
driver.switch_to.alert.send_keys(username + Keys.TAB + password)
time.sleep(3)
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. The issue is that each time when I make a new entry this pop shows up. To proceed for next entry I have to press ESC or the program will break itself ( I don't have to sign again using that pop up ). 

[Alert_example_img](https://discussions.apple.com/content/attachment/153168040)

I have tried following code and it didn't work. 

`time.sleep(3)
driver.switch_to.alert.dismiss()`